# DownGrading iOS to Previous Version Officially

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.2, downgrade

I 'am Having iPad 3 , iOS 5.1 and I have latest Lion Version and X-code latest installed. But When I m Connecting the device ,X-code Can't Find my device.

But I have another system with Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and X-code 4.2 installed (iOS 5 SDK) Which FInds my Device correctly But the problem is its Doesn't Support the Version.its asks the device iOS to be downgrade to testing.

So I would like to test my app on older ios version (iOS 5), so my Question is :

1. is there any standard way to downgrade Device iOS 5.1 to iOS 5.0 or earlier so that i can test my Application ?
2. Can i Able to Restore/Upgrade again after completing my task ?

   Any link to Official Page would be great.Please help Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you cannot downgrade iPad 3 os officially.

Comment: Thanks to all for Responding my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no way to downgrade officially. apple does not allow to downgrade your iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I just update my computer's iOS SDK any time i update my development devices, you can get it at the bottom of the iOS dev center main page

Comment: Thanks Dan.I also updated my Computer's iOS SDK ,But that system Can't find my device so ,i m trying to test with another system.

Comment: I honestly don't know if it is possible to get access to anything other than the latest version of iOS